# Scope with association .any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, tags, scopes

I have two models, employees, and departments. Employes belong Departments through Positions. In a select tag I'd like to list only departments that have employees in them.

Right now I have:

```
@current_company.departments.collect {|d| [d.title, d.id] if d.employees.any?}
```

Which leaves me with a couple of nil select options. I thought I could write a scope for depmartments that would work like @current_company.departments.with_employees:

```
scope :with_employees, :where => (self.employees.any?)
```

I realize that won't work, but I'm stuck on what I should do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that a join is an inner join, which does precisely what you want - writing the join as a scope...

```
scope :with_employees, :joins => :employees
```

Comment: +1 for reusability, brilliant clarity, extensibility, simplicity and efficiency.

Comment: I forgot to mention that employees belong to departments :through => :positions. Still applicable?

Comment: Hopefully you've tried it already and found out that yes, it works through a join table too.  Time to accept my answer now, feed me ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need nil select options why you can't use `.compact` method?

```
@current_company.departments.collect {|d| [d.title, d.id] if d.employees.any?}.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

Or yet another way to do it...

```
@current_company.departments.reject {|d| d.employees.empty?}.collect {|d| [d.title, d.id]}
```

The beauty of Ruby is there are so many ways to do anything ;)